# node.js and expressjs render a template with a URL param

Tags: node.js, express

Currently a user comes to my register page with an invitation ID

Example: http://www.mysite.com/user/register/50e203eb4d37bdfd22000042

The page loads and the form loads etc.... all is great. I then do some back end validation and if validation fails I call the res.render with the messages and the form data:

```
res.render('user/register', {
    messages: messages 
    , form: form 

});
```

It all works as expected however when the render occurs it puts the user back to:

http://www.mysite.com/user/register  (its missing the invite_id)

How can I pass along a URL param with the res render?

If I do:

```
res.render('user/register/50e203eb4d37bdfd22000042', {
    messages: messages 
    , form: form 

});
```

Its actually looking for that 50e203.... file and giving me the 404 not found

Thanks!

Comment: This post seems similar to what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784753/passing-route-control-with-optional-parameter-after-root-in-express

Answer (score 4):

Are you perhaps confusing `res.render()` with `app.get()`? It looks like you're trying to specify a route in that second example: `res.render('user/register/50e203eb4d37bdfd22000042'...` - but res.render doesn't specify routes, you need app[METHOD] for that, where app is an express instance.

In order to handle a GET request to /user/register/someinvite, use:

```
app.get('/user/register/:invitation', function(req, res, next) {
// in here you can access the invitation id with req.params.invitation
  res.render('user/register');
});
```

Comment: Actually I was an idiot.... I just needed to concact the ID into the form action in the jade template... I was mixing up the res.render with the url!