# Node express.Router().route(/verb/:optionalParameter)?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I use node `express` `Router` module, and it's `route()` method.

I need to accept an optional parameter, this way:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/verb/:optionalParameter').get(function(req, res, next) {
  // ...
}
```

How do I specify `optionalParameter`?
I did try:

```
router.route('/verb/:optionalParameter*?').get(function(req, res, next) {
```

and

```
curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:3000/verb/option1
```

works just fine, but

```
curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:3000/verb
```

spits a 404...

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious... :-( Any clue?

Comment: Did you take a look to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784753/passing-route-control-with-optional-parameter-after-root-in-express

Comment: Did you try to remove the asterics in the route url?
Like so: `router.route('/verb/:optionalPatrameter?').get(function(req, res, next) {` instead of: `router.route('/verb/:optionalPatrameter*?').get(function(req, res, next) {`

Comment: @Mayas: It's not about `express Router` module ... ;-(

Comment: Tried just now: same 404... :-(

Comment: You're right.
Why don't you do this instead?
`var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var app = express()

app.route('/verb/:optionalParameter?').get(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('hello world')
})`
I just tried it and I get 'hello world' for /verb/1 and /verb/ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response it's 404 because don't exist route `/verb`, only `/verb/:optionalParameter`.

For works, it's need to create another route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/verb/:optionalParameter').get(function(req, res, next) {
  // ...
}

// route localhost:3000/verb
router.route('/verb').get(function(req, res, next) {
  // ...
}
```

And try:

```
curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:3000/verb
```

Comment: Well, not a real solution: in the first route it's a **mandatory** parameter... :-) I was asking for a way to write **one single**  route... If it's not possible, I'll follow your advise...

Comment: I believe it's not possible, each route trigger one action. For another URL, require another route (get, put, post, delete). One URL passes a parameter and another does not.

Comment: Ok. For go far away, consulting the documentation: http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var app = express()
app.route('/verb/:optionalParameter?').get(function(req, res, next) { console.log('hello world') })
```

Comment: Can you summarize the differences between `express.Router().route()` and `express.route()` ?

Comment: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.route
I guess the first is a deprecated way to do it.