# What to do when NodeJS rest api is sendind status 404 while using parameters?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am having a strange problem while writing my api. I am using Nodejs and express. The problem occurs when i try to use GET with parameters.

This is my routes code

```
    router.get('/addFriends/:email', (req, res, next) =>{
  const email = req.params.email;
  UserSchema.find({email: email}, { "friendsPending.emailSender": 1, _id : 0}, (err, data) =>{
    if(err){
      res.status(404).send(err);
    }else{
      res.status(200).send(data[0]);
    }
  });

});
```

This is my call in Postman : /users/addFriends?email=a

When running this call, server returns 404 status. It happened even when i tested it with another get call.
Any comments are appriciated, however other POST and GET calls work normally (they use body not parameters). Thanks

Comment: Side note: What you're doing is not RESTful at all; You might want to change it to `router.post('/friends/:email', (req, res, next) => {})` since you're creating a friend association.

Comment: `next` parameter in your function is not necessary. it's for pass router to other matchable routers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed query params and url params. To make your example working, you need to use `/addFriends/my-email@gmail.com` instead of `/users/addFriends?email=a`.

If you need to send emails via query params (everything after `?`) use `req.query` in your controller instead of `req.params.email`.

Answer (score 0):

This route definition:

```
router.get('/addFriends/:email', ...);
```

expects a URL that looks like this:

```
/addFriends/someEmail
```

And, you would use `req.params.email` to refer to the "someEmail" value in the URL path.

Not what you are trying to use:

```
/addFriends?email=a
```

---

If you want to use a URL such as (a URL with a query parameter):

```
/addFriends?email=a
```

Then, you would have a route definition like this:

```
router.get('/addFriends', ...);
```

And, then you would refer to `req.query.email` in the route handler.  Query parameters (things after the `?` in the URL) come from the `req.query` object.

---

In Express, route definitions match the path of the URL, not the query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `/addFriends/:param` you force the router to match any request tha have a part in path as `:param`.For example:

```
/users/addFriends/toFavorates // will **match**
```

```
/users/addFriends/toFavorates?email=a // will **match**
```

```
/users/addFriends?email=a // will **not** match
```

if you want to make `:param` as optional part of url path put a `?` after it

```
/addFriends/:param?
```

it will tell express route that `:param` is an optinal part. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784753/passing-route-control-with-optional-parameter-after-root-in-express)
express uses [path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) for matching the route paths. read the documentation for more options