# Node express to catch all optional parameters after url-path-params

Tags: node.js, express, url, optional-parameters

Following up on [Passing route control with optional parameter after root in express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784753/),
I'm working on a simple url-shortening app and would like to catch anything afer the url-path-params (`/link/:id`) into a single variable. E.g., for:

http://localhost:3002/link/XYZ/abc/def?access_token=nQevH_hZSjs3qdOoLNnAIITwqd3lCdkq&expires_in=7200&token_type=Bearer

I hope to get `id=XYZ` then `rest=abc/def?access_token=nQevH_hZSjs3qdOoLNnAIITwqd3lCdkq&expires_in=7200&token_type=Bearer`

I tried `/link/:id/:rest?` but it's not working for the example url.

```js
router.get("/link/:id/:rest?", getLinkAndParams)

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

exports.getLinkAndParams = async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id
    let rest = req.params.rest
    rest = rest ? `/${rest}` : ""
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

`routes.get("/link/*", getLinkAndParams);`

**Example:-**

```
router.get("/link/:id/*", getLinkAndParams);

exports.getLinkAndParams = async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const rest = req.params[0]; // the rest of the path and query string will be captured in this variable
  console.log(`id: ${id}`);
  console.log(`rest: ${rest}`);
  // ...
};
```

Comment: @xpt I'm creating a restful-APIs framework if you're interested let me know we're looking for contributors

https://github.com/Zain-ul-din
https://github.com/RandomsDev
Discord id: https://discord.gg/ga2AWxWK

Comment: @xpt One possible cause of this issue is the router.get("/link/:id/*" route is being registered after the 404 error handling middleware. In this case, the 404 error handling middleware will catch all requests, including those that match the router.get("/link/:id/*" route.One possible cause of this issue is that the router.get("/link/:id/*" route is being registered after the 404 error handling middleware. In this case, the 404 error handling middleware will catch all requests, including those that match the router.get("/link/:id/*" route.

Comment: Thanks athena, I'm too green to JS world to be of any help. Yep, that url rule works, just that the `rest` is only `/abc/def`, not the full url param string.

Comment: @xpt no problem, I love to work with you if you want!